# What is Safari's window height after the debug console is activated?

Tags: ipad, safari, viewport

I probably didn't look into the right places, but I was unable to find out what is the iPad's Safari window height after the debug console is activated.

For the width it's simple, it remains the standard 1024 pixels for landscape, 728 for portrait.

But what is it's standard height of the browser's viewport, with the console activated? [Similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449028/height-of-the-ipad-safari-viewport) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880520/how-large-is-the-usable-area-in-ipad-safari?rq=1) did not contain this seemingly simple answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking with an output debug div on all the iPad generations (the first three, at the time this post is written), with iOs 5 and 6, I determined Safari's height (the visible portion that displays the website) for both orientations, with and without the debug console.

**Portrait orientation**

- without the console: 672px
- with the console:    622px

**Landscape orientation**

- without the console: 928px
- with the console:    878px

So the debug console has a height of **50 pixels**, and the navigation bar **96 pixels**