# Mobile Safari on iPhone 5: Visible area size?

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile-safari

What's the size of the visible area in Mobile Safari on the iPhone 5 in default configuration, in landscape and in portrait orientation?

Comment: Fire up your iPhone simulator and screen captures!

Comment: I may do that, if the simulator would run on my ThinkPad...

Comment: Check my answer to similar question, might help a little - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205812/jquery-js-ios-4-and-document-height-problems

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## iOS6

According to Kyle Larson's article [iPhone 5 Web Design](http://www.kylejlarson.com/blog/2012/iphone-5-web-design/), the resolutions are:

- Portrait: 640 × 888 px (= 320 × 444 double px)
- Landscape: 1136 × 392 px (= 568 × 196 double px)

That is with navigation bar, i.e *in default configuration*, like I wrote in my question.

## iOS7

According to @astletron, the resolutions are:

- Portrait: 640 × 920 px
- Landscape: 1136 × 424 px

Comment: Worth noting that those figures are for iOS 6.  Figures for iOS 7 are 640 x 920 and 1136 x 424 hardware pixels.

Comment: Why those iOS7 resolutions? I have iPhone 5 with iOS 10 and resolutions are the same as for iOS6

Comment: would prefer the double px sizes listed first as they are usually the actionable values people are looking for

Answer (score 1):

**Portait:**

- Height - 892 (716 + 176 (the difference between the new and old devices))
- Width - 640

**Landscape**:

- Height - 420
- Width - 1136

Comment: Landscape cannot be 640 px in height: There needs to be space for the UI elements at the top and bottom. Also, it would be great if you could give a link to the source of those numbers!

Comment: Oh, sorry - I once created a mobile web that just had an image and I was given these numbers by the UI designer. I updated the landscape numbers. I'm not sure if there is a programmatic way to retrieve the window size of safari.

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#technotes/tn2010/tn2262/index.html

Comment: Concerning programmatically: How about `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight`? I will mark your question as answered, once I can be certain about the numbers. Without source, I am still hesitant.

Answer (score -1):

If you're after general viewport size, [iPhone5 portrait width is 320 and landscape width is 568](http://viewportsizes.com/?filter=iphone).

Comment: Please write the size in your answer. A link may rot.

Comment: width 320 it the same with iPhone4