# iPhone/Mobile Safari: Getting a reliable viewport height

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, mobile-safari, kendo-ui, viewport

Is there a way to get a reliable viewport height value from mobile Safari? I've been struggling for days now and I know that I am not the only one with this problem.
Even toolkits like http://responsejs.com didn't help me. How to Sencha Touch or Kendo UI get the screen height, does somebody know that? Is that reliable?

Comment: Check my answer to similar question, it should help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205812/jquery-js-ios-4-and-document-height-problems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I always use this:
http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.viewport.Default-method-getWindowHeight

```
Ext.Viewport.getWindowHeight();
```